# midnight commander: specify commandline options in global config file

Tags: linux, mc

I want to start mc always with the `--nomouse` option. Is there a way to put this option into the (global) config file, so that I don't have to type it every time ?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't an option in the configuration menu, so I would guess not.  However, you could always set:

```
alias mc='mc --nomouse'
```

in `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: thanks. I will use `alias` if I don' find anything better